# I need to use a symbol like this |---| with a continuous line between the two vertical ones

Tags: symbols

I need a symbol to refer in my text a connection used in some figures. 
I need something like it could be expected from a `\vdashv`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: H, perhaps in a sans serif font.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can join `\vdash` and `\dashv`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\vdashv}{\vdash\joinrel\dashv}

\begin{document}

$A \vdashv B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need a shorter symbol,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\vdashv}{%
  \vdash\mathrel{\mkern-9mu}\dashv
}

\begin{document}

$A \vdashv B$

\end{document}
```

This is the maximum amount of backing up. With `\joinrel` it is -3mu.

[image]

A different realization with shorter vertical bars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\connection}{\mapstochar\relbar\mapsfromchar}

\begin{document}

$A \connection B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well...this is the better answer :)

Comment: Really nice answer.  just in case. It is a clever way to shorter the vertical lines?

Comment: @herito Added a version with shorter bars.

Comment: Great. I found that \leftfootline with your previous strategy could also do the trick

Comment: @herito Be careful, though: `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` changes *all* math symbols in a way that is usually incompatible with the text font.

Comment: Add another pair of curly braces to be able to use these seamlessly in subscript. E.g. 
`\newcommand{\vdashv}{{\vdash\joinrel\dashv}}`

Comment: @Wouter No, if you want to preserve its nature of relation symbol. Use `_{\connection}`

Answer (score 6):

I am *not* totally serious...

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\dashv$}$\!\dashv$

\end{document}
```

**Not so good as an image export**

[image]

**Better in Adobe Reader**

[image]

**No luck in [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)**

[image]

---

### Update

`\reflectbox` (mirroring a symbol) from the `graphicx` package does a better job.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% \rotatebox
\usepackage{rotating}

% \reflectbox
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\textbackslash rotatebox} \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\dashv$}$\!\dashv$
\texttt{\textbackslash reflectbox} \reflectbox{$\dashv$}$\!\dashv$

\end{document}
```

[image]